Cannot build solution with MsBuild task
Here's the target I defined in Directory.Build.props file:
 <Target Name="BuildAndDeployTools" BeforeTargets="Build" >
   <Message Text="Building Tools Solution ..." Importance="high"/>
   <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/tools/tools.sln" Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU"/>
   <Message Text="Tools Solution is built." Importance="high"/>
 </Target>

But when I build my solution I get the following error:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'tools\DiscoveredTestsAsJsonTestLogger\DiscoveredTestsAsJsonTestLogger.Tests\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

My assumption would be that Build target is called for the tools solution.
If I explicitly specify Targets="Build", I still get the same error.
If I specify Targets="Restore,Compile", I get error from .sln.metaproj file:

tools\tools.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "Compile" does not exist in the project.

If I just run dotnet msbuild .\tools.sln /Target:"Restore;Build" on clean tools solution it is built without any issue.

Compile is not a target on a solution file. Use Targets="Restore;Build".

Ok, my mistake was in using coma instead of semicolon
